# How to scheduling different repeating notifications with a condition in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am having trouble with scheduling repeating notifications that each have to check a condition. I have been using a task manager to schedule timers for when each notification should be sent, then at that time, before sending the notification, check my condition. All of today, I thought it was working because I was getting notifications, but it turns out that the condition was never being checked properly. For background, the condition is an API call, and my logs never show any request being received. Here is the swift code I have now:

```
    let notifications: [NotificationConfig] = [...] // notification objects here

    func buildMap() -> [Int: [NotificationConfig]] {
        var times = [Int: [NotificationConfig]]()
        
        for notif in self.notifications {
            for time in notif.times {
                if let value = times[time] {
                    times[time]!.append(notif)
                } else {
                    times[time] = [notif]
                }
            }
        }
        
        return times
    }
    
    func makeCheck(notification: NotificationConfig) -> () async -> Bool {
        
        return {
            print("Called function already")
            return await self.checkCondition(value: notification.type, hours: notification.hours)
        }
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        // Declare the task variable
        var task: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = .invalid
        
        // Schedule the background task to run periodically
        task = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "BackgroundTask") {
            // Handle expiration if needed
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(task)
        }
        
        // Define a task to request notification authorization asynchronously
        // Request notification authorization
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
            
            if granted {
                print("Notification authorization granted")
                
                // Continue with scheduling notifications
                
                let times: [Int: [NotificationConfig]] = self.buildMap()
                let calendar = Calendar.current
                let timeZone = TimeZone.current
                
                for (desiredHour, notifs) in times {
                    for (i, notif) in notifs.enumerated() {
                        let currentTime = Date()
                        
                        var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(in: timeZone, from: currentTime)
                        dateComponents.hour = desiredHour
                        dateComponents.minute = 0
                        dateComponents.second = 0
                        
                        guard var desiredTime = calendar.date(from: dateComponents) else {
                            continue
                        }
                        
                        // if desired time in the past, make it in the future by adding a day
                        if desiredTime.compare(currentTime) == .orderedAscending {
                            desiredTime = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: desiredTime)!
                        }
                        
                        let timeDifference = desiredTime.timeIntervalSince(currentTime)
                        let shouldSendNotification = self.makeCheck(notification: notif)
                        
                        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeDifference, repeats: true) { _ in
                            Task {
                                print("Starting timed function")
                                if await shouldSendNotification() {
                                    print("Sending notificaiton")
                                    self.sendNotification(notif: notif, hour: desiredHour, minute: i)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        print("Timer Interrupt scheduled in \(timeDifference) seconds for \(notif.id) at \(desiredHour)")
                    }
                }
                
                // End the background task
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(task)
                print("background task ended")
            } else {
                print("Notification authorization denied")
            }
            
        }
        return true
    }

    func sendNotification(notif: NotificationConfig, hour: Int, minute: Int?) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = notif.title
        content.body = notif.body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = hour
        dateComponents.minute = minute ?? 0
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
        
        let identifier = "notification_\(hour)_\(minute ?? 0)"
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error scheduling notification for hour \(hour): \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Notification scheduled successfully for hour \(hour)")
            }
        }
    }


    func checkCondition(value: NotificationType, hours: Int) async -> Bool {
        // Build url
        var urlString = MY_URL + "/Notification"
        urlString += "?value="+value.rawValue+"&hours="+String(hours)
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("Error: Something wrong with url.")
            return false
        }

        // build full request
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
        urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
            "Token": API_KEY
        ]
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        // make request
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
        
            // ensure success
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                // handle if not 200
                print("Notification response not 200")
                return false
            }

            return try JSONDecoder().decode(Bool.self, from: data) 
        }
        catch {
            print("Error: something went wrong calling api", error)
            return false
        }
    }
```

I am certain my API is working, and that my NotificationConfig Objects make sense. I have many API calls just like this, and they pretty much never fail before the request is sent (which is not reached here), so it is almost definitely not the API call. I also understand that the background task here will immediately end, and wont reschedule the timers/notifications, but I know how to do that if I can get this properly working. Any tips on how to make sure that the condition is checked immediately before the notification is sent? I'm struggling to find resources for this specific topic. Any and all suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you will need to create the `UNNotificationRequest` and add it to the `UNUserNotificationCenter` by using `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)`. In the `UNNotificationRequest` you can configure your trigger to a certain time.

Then, what you really need is to create a Notification Service that extends from `UNNotificationServiceExtension` and override the `didReceive`. Check this documentation:
[UNNotificationServiceExtension documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension).

This will allow you to mutate the notification as needed before it is visible for the user.

Since you want to only show in a certain condition, you should also read this:
[Silence push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_usernotifications_filtering)

Never used this, but seems that's exactly what you want.